# jupyter python improve plot or graph quality

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have changed of laptop and installed anaconda (4.3.0) but using Jupyter Notebook the graph plots have different colors first when I open (the orignal from my old laptop) and after I run the cell

```
x = np.random.rand(200)
y = np.random.rand(200)
size = np.random.rand(200)*30
color = np.random.rand(200)
plt.scatter(x, y, size, color)
plt.colorbar()
plt.ylabel("foo", fontsize="large")
```

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qG5wY.png)

[New](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0Vei.png)

I will like to know how to maintain the old resolution or quality of the plots

Answer (score 1):

You can use `plt.style.use('classic')`. Matplotlib has changed it's default styles which I think is what causes the changes you've encountered (see http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#default-style-changes).